# Youtube video fullscreen making page fullscreen

Tags: html, wordpress, video, youtube, fullscreen

i have a wordpress website and i am using iframe to embed youtube video. Issue is when i click on fullscreen icon of video, my page with whole content go in fullscreen mode.

Its a weird issue and i have worked hours to solve this issue. Please check this link.
[website link](http://cr7-king.com/2017/09/06/cristiano-ronaldo-amazing-freestyle/)

using my code as:-

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Di7G4nbpyDg?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

i know direct website links is not acceptable but this is something need to fix. Any response will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On Wordpress use `[youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XX11XX11X]`
xx11xx11x is only example.
Wordpress wants to keep sites prtoected from iframes. So you are not able to publish `<iframe>`s.
Did you got it?

Edit: In your case use: `[youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Di7G4nbpyDg]`

like this:
[image]

I have no permission to show you the full video link.

Comment: I wanna know how do you use it.

Comment: i just used wordpress add media and upload from external url

Comment: `[embed]https://www.youtube.com/embed/Di7G4nbpyDg[/embed]` This is wordpress gave when i upload

Comment: Did try with yours but just got the url nothing else

Comment: No, that's not what I use.

Comment: I mean it's not at yoursite.wordpress.com/wp-admin?

Comment: `[youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Di7G4nbpyDg]` you gave me this but i just show the complete text nothing else

Comment: No. this is on my own domain

Comment: Just write that code what I provided  where ever you want. Like to the middle of text.

Comment: i wrote it and what i got is `[youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Di7G4nbpyDg]` on frontend

Comment: Look my screenshot

Comment: So write that plant of text to graphical section.

Comment: You can also use iframe, and hope Wordpress converts it.

Comment: i sorted this out i think. there were some classes conflict